# What's wrong with this BAT file using FINDSTR?

Tags: batch-file

I need to take input of a list of links that go to pages of similar format, with the difference of content and one tag.

EDIT

```
input.txt
/category/apples-and-oranges.html
/category/pineapples.html
/category/asparagus.html
/category/brussel-sprouts.html
/category/passion-fruit.html
```

Assume that the pages involving fruit have `<h1>Fruit!</h1>` while the non-fruit pages don't, but they're under one category. The program would check those extensions to `http://www.mysite.com` and then create a new list:

```
output.txt
/category/apples-and-oranges.html
/category/pineapples.html
/category/passion-fruit.html
```

Here's what I've got so far:

```
for /f %%A in (input.txt) DO (
    for "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%b in ('FINDSTR [/R] [/I] [/S] [/C:"<H1>.*Fruit!.*</H1>"] [[http://]www.mysite.com/%%A[*.html]]') DO (
    echo ^<%%A> > <output.txt>
)
```

)

Comment: Can you show us an actual example of the input and the actual result you want to achieve?

Comment: what have you tried so far and what problems you had? To get you started, use this hint... take a look at `FOR` and `FINDSTR` commands and try this `FOR /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ('FINDSTR /R /I /S "<H1>.*</H1>" *.htm') do ECHO ^<a href="%%a"^>%%b^</a^>`

Comment: Thank you @PA, but I'm still a little confused by what you mean. I'll try it out and get back to you if I have any more questions.

Comment: I edited it to show where I'm at now... I'm still not getting it to run though...

Comment: Are you missing a `/f` on your second `for` ?

Comment: @PA. and James [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15419314/2167103) is a fantastic piece of code reading html websites in batchfiles without any further external apps or installs - just wanted to mention this technic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems in your approach. First of all FINDSTR cannot find in remote URLs. So you need to download them.

Begin with the following code, that uses `CURL` for downloading, to get you started.

```
@echo off
FOR /F %%A in (input.txt) DO (
  curl --output temp.html http:www.mysite.com/%%A 
  FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%B in ('FINDSTR /I /R "<H1>.*Fruit.*</H1>" temp.html') DO (
    ECHO %%A
  )
)
```

**Edit:**

**cURL** is not a Windows command, it's an external utility. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL . You'll need to install it. There is another well know tool for web download,  **GNU Wget** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget . For more options, see this question on Superuser.com https://superuser.com/questions/299754/wget-curl-alternative-native-to-windows

Comment: I keep getting the following error when I'm trying to monkey around with it: `curl is not recognized as an external or internal command`

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't do enough background research, I'm really sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, you really got me out of a bind and I learned a great new utility for batch files I didn't know! Thank you!