# Odd behavior IF statement in Batch

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, text

I have a very simple Batch script that I'm working on

I'm considering implementing an updater with wget and version files locally and hosted on my server (yet I'm using Batch for some reason)

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (version.txt) do set version=%%x 
if "%version%" == "1.0.0" (echo yes)
```

the text file it's referencing contains nothing but

```
1.0.0
```

Not even a new line. Echoing `%version%` gives me `1.0.0` in the console, but the if statement gets nothing.

Anyone wanna point out my error? I'm honestly clueless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have a naughy space on the end of the `set` command.

Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N"

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned. `set /a` can safely be used "quoteless".

Comment: So, I think I understand what you're saying

Comment: Whoops, comments on newline

Comment: I changed the script a little
`@echo off`
`for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in ("%CD%\version.txt") do set /a curr=%%x`
`if "%curr%" == "1.0.0" (echo yes)`
And now it tells me Bad Parameter (Specifically when I added /a)

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky.  You have a space at the end of `set version=%%x`.

As a general point of scripting convention, whenever you set a variable to a string in a batch script, unless you have a specific reason not to do so, you should do `set "variable=value"` with the var=value pair quoted.  That helps avoid problems like this.  Your `for /f` line should end with `set "version=%%x"`

With the trailing space, you're basically saying `if "1.0.0 " == "1.0.0"`, which is false.

As a side note, it is possible to fetch the content from your web server [without using wget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15419314/1683264) if you wish.